# How to plot points on google map with subgurim

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps, subgurim-maps

Everything was working fine about an hour ago, but now I am having errors with anything I try.

```
strFullAddress = "texas. usa"

GeoCode = GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(strFullAddress, sMapKey)
Dim gLatLng As New Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lat, GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lng)
Dim oMarker As New Subgurim.Controles.GMarker(gLatLng)

GMap1.Add(oMarker)
```

was working perfectly before. Now this just creates a marker left of Africa. I have the same results for any address, or any lattitude... No one else seems to have this problem and I'm out of ideas...
So, any ideas as to what could be going on?

EDIT:

I tried this example code which also worked for me when i was learning how to use subgurim and it also just puts a marker next to africa.

```
    Dim strFullAddress As String
    Dim sMapKey As String =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("googlemaps.subgurim.net")
    Dim GeoCode As Subgurim.Controles.GeoCode

    ' Combine our address fields to create the full address.  The street,
    ' suburb and country should be seperated by  periods (.)
    strFullAddress = txtStreetAddress.Text & ". " & txtSuburb.Text & ". " & txtCountry.Text

    ' Work out the longitude and latitude
    GeoCode = GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(strFullAddress, sMapKey)
Dim gLatLng As New Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lat, GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lng)
    ' Display the map
    GMap1.setCenter(GLatLng, 16, Subgurim.Controles.GMapType.GTypes.Normal)
    Dim oMarker As New Subgurim.Controles.GMarker(GLatLng)
    GMap1.Add(oMarker)
    GMap1.GZoom = 5
```

Comment: If you are getting a mark off of the western coast of Africa, then your latitude and longitude values are `0, 0`. You need to put a break point on your lines of code and see if your address is incorrect (`texas. usa`) or your map key is not working when you make the call to the Google geo-coding logic. Does `texas, usa` work as an address?

Comment: this code was working not too long ago though. I haven't messed with anything. I tried texas, usa and it didn't work for me either :(

Comment: Is the `sMapKey` still valid?  If you make a request through the browser, like this: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&key=YOURMAPKEYHERE`, does that return a map centered over New York city?

Comment: I get an error when i try this with my key...

Comment: i tried this though, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&sensor=true&key=my key    with my key and it did work

Comment: The problem seems to be GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(strFullAddress, sMapKey) returns 0,0 every time. Is there a limit to how many times you can use getgeocoderequest per day?

Comment: Did you change versions of Subgurim?

Comment: @baba There is a limit (of about 2500 I think) but I highly doubt he has gone over it just testing this by himself in a dev environment.

Comment: @adaam No, I've used the new version only. It's working again today, so i guess I must have reached the limit. Thanks everyone for the help